# How to "combine" two int arrays?

Tags: c, arrays

Hello i have a little problem trying to "mix" two string arrays, i have searched about it but i have only found how to merge them or concatenate them, but thats not what i need.

i have two int arrays like this:

```
int no_items = 5;
int parent1[no_items], parent2[no_items];
```

if the arrays contains for example:

```
parent1[0] = 1;
parent1[1] = 2;
parent1[2] = 3;
parent1[3] = 4;
parent1[4] = 5;
```

and:

```
parent2[0] = 5;
parent2[1] = 1;
parent2[2] = 2;
parent2[3] = 3;
parent2[4] = 4;
```

given a "cross" point, for example 2:
parent1 should have his 2 first elements and the rest of parent2, and parent2 should have his first 2 elements and the rest of parent1. So the result should be:

```
parent1: 1,2 | 5,3,4
parent2: 5,1 | 2,3,4
```

where "|" is the break point index and **the rest of elements should not be repeated.**

How can i get this kind of mixing two int arrays? Thanks you!

at the moment i have this:

```
 for(i = 0; i < cross_point; i++)
    {
        sprintf(buffer, "%d,", parent1[i]);
        strcat(line1, buffer);
    }
    for(i = 0; i < cross_point; i++)
    {
        sprintf(buffer, "%d,", parent2[i]);
        strcat(line2, buffer);
    }
```

but i don´t know how to go further than the cross point.

Comment: The 5,3,4 makes no sense in the parent1 result. *Neither* sequence has that subsequence to begin with. Other than that, this seems straight forward.

Comment: I assume you meant: `parent1: 1,2 | 2,3,4` and `parent2: 5,1 | 3,4,5`?

Comment: Also, correct me if I'm wrong, but what you try to do is to **swap** a sub-part of two arrays, right?

Comment: This question really needs some clarification, especially with the example given. I'm honestly not entirely sure what the aim is.

Comment: Same here. And I don't really get the difficulty of the task either. We might be missing some important information.

Comment: well, its parent1: 1,2 | 5,3,4 and parent2: 5,1 | 2,3,4 because elements cannot repeat, and so i put the rest of items in parent1 as they appeared on parent 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int *find(int *begin, int *end, int value)
{
    int *p = begin;
    for ( ; p != end; ++p)
        if (*p == value) break;
    return p;
}

int i, j;
int output1[no_items] = {0};
int output2[no_items] = {0};
int crosspoint = 3;
memcpy(output1, parent1, crosspoint * sizeof(int));
for (i = crosspoint, j = 0; i < no_items; ++i)
{
    while (find(output1, output1+i, parent2[j]) != output1+i) ++j;
    output1[i] = parent2[j];
}
memcpy(output2, parent2, crosspoint * sizeof(int));
for (i = crosspoint, j = 0; i < no_items; ++i)
{
    while (find(output2, output2+i, parent1[j]) != output2+i) ++j;
    output2[i] = parent1[j];
}
memcpy(parent1, output1, sizeof(parent1));
memcpy(parent2, output2, sizeof(parent2));
```

Demo: http://ideone.com/xUt6nQ

Comment: This almost worked fine, but got a little detail at the end: 
if parent1 = 8,3,6,9,7,4,5,10,1,2 and parent2= 10,3,2,9,4,7,5,8,6,1
and the cross_point = 3 the result is:

parent1:8,3,6 | 10,2,7,5,1,0,4198595
parent2:10,3,2 | 8,6,7,5,1,0,4198595

Comment: @user3663133 Updated answer to fix the bug.

Answer (score 0):

something like this should do it if you aren't concerned about creating temporaries:

```
int no_items = 5;
int output1[no_items];
int output2[no_items];

for (int i = 0; i < no_items; i++){
    if(i < crosspoint){
         output1[i] = parent1[i];
         output2[i] = parent2[i];
    }else{
         output1[i] = parent2[i];
         output2[i] = parent1[i];
    }
}
```

If you are concerned about temporaries you need to swap the values, the logic should be fairly similar to above.

```
int no_items = 5;
int temp = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < no_items; i++){
    if(i < crosspoint){
          /* don't need to do anything here */
    }else{
         temp = parent1[i];
         parent1[i] = parent2[i];
         parent2[i] = temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, It can be achieved more elegantly with only one temporary buffer.

Comment: +1 Your last solution is even more elegant that the one I was thinking of. However, it would even be more elegant if you would skip swapping the first elements by starting your for loop at `crosspoint` instead of 0.

Comment: The values after cross point should not duplicate with the value _before_. Thus element-wise swap does not work.

Comment: @timrau Where is that written, in the OP?

Comment: _the rest of elements should not be repeated._ right after the output example.

Comment: thats right Timrau, values after cross point should not be duplicated. Thus element swap doesn´t work